# Why is vld4q_f32 not the same as 4x vld1q_f32?

Tags: c++, intrinsics, neon

```
const float* H; //input data from elsewhere
const float32x4x4_t hCols = vld4q_f32(H);

const float32x4_t hCol0 = vld1q_f32(H + 0);
const float32x4_t hCol1 = vld1q_f32(H + 4);
const float32x4_t hCol2 = vld1q_f32(H + 8);
const float32x4_t hCol3 = vld1q_f32(H + 12);
```

My code which uses hCol0, hCol1, hCol2, hCol3 are replaced with hCols.val[0], hCols.val[1], hCols.val[2], hCols.val[3] but now I am getting very weird output.

Are these two loads not exactly the same with vld4q_f32 potentially faster?

Comment: If `H` is a `float*`, remember that C address math scales by the operand size, but asm doesn't.  So probably you want `H + 1`, `H + 2` to get asm that loads from `[reg + #4]`, `[reg + #8]`, etc.  It's often helpful to check the compiler output to make sure it looks like you're expecting (can catch correctness and performance bugs).

Comment: @PeterCordes H + 4, 8, 12 is correctly handled by the compiler. It's the `vld4` instruction itself that makes the difference. The lack of such delightful instructions in `AVX` is really shocking to me.

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE: oops, I didn't realize vld4q was loading 4x4 = 16 floats, and that vld1q was loading 4 floats.  I guessed it was loading 1 (with a broadcast-load or scalar load into a zero-extended vector reg, like x86's `movss xmm0, [mem]`).  I definitely get mixed up sometimes and offset my C pointers by the byte count when I've been looking at / thinking about how I want the asm to come out, so my first guess was that was the problem :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vld4` is a very different instruction than `vld1` to start with.

While `vld1` is a straightforward load, `vld4` is a a spread-load, where each value gets distributed among the four registers, element after element, register after register.

```
vld4q_f32(pSrc) will translate to:

vld4.32 {d0, d2, d4, d6}, [pSrc]!
vld4.32 {d1, d3, d5, d7}, [pSrc]

*pSrc:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E

================================================

And the values are loaded as following:
q0 (d0 + d1): 0, 4, 8, C
q1 (d2 + d3): 1, 5, 9, D
q2 (d4 + d5): 2, 6, A, E
q3 (d6 + d7): 3, 7, B, F
```

In assembly, it is possible to load multiple registers straight with a single instruction like:

```
vld1.32 {q0, q1}, [pSrc]!
vld1.32 {q2, q3}, [pSrc]

And the values are loaded as following:
q0 (d0 + d1): 0, 1, 2, 3
q1 (d2 + d3): 4, 5, 6, 7
q2 (d4 + d5): 8, 9, A, B
q3 (d6 + d7): C, D, E, F
```

In intrinsics, however, you have to do it register by register:
float32x4x4_t hCols;

```
hCols.val[0] = vld1q_f32(H + 0);
hCols.val[1] = vld1q_f32(H + 4);
hCols.val[2] = vld1q_f32(H + 8);
hCols.val[3] = vld1q_f32(H + 12);
```

On Android Studio 3.01, `vld1q_f32_x4` is defined for that purpose, but it still seems buggy. I haven't been able to successfully build at least.

BTW, are you trying to do 4x4 matrix multiplication? Congrats, you just found how to transpose the matrix automatically on-the-fly in `vld4`;

Don't waste your time with intrinsics though. **The assembly version runs almost three times as fast** whereas I did the 1:1 translation to intrinsics, compiled by Clang that came with Android Studio 3.01. It's really annoying.

Using intrinsics is a pure waste of time, definitely, at least on ARM.

Comment: I'm surprised compilers do such a bad job with intrinsics.  On x86 it's usually possible to get the asm instructions you want by using intrinsics, and structuring your loop carefully.  (But x86 isn't very sensitive to instruction scheduling; is scheduling the main issue hurting compilers on ARM?)

Comment: At such a huge performance hit, I didn't even bother checking the disassembly, my blood pressure is already high enough. For 4x4 float32 matrix multiplication, you need 12 128-bit registers, and `aarch32` has 16 where only four has to be preserved. The moment I saw `vpush` in the beginning of the disassembly, it was game over for me.

Comment: Yes I am trying to do 4x4 multiplication. Do you have a link to your arm asm solution?

Comment: @DatChu I'll be posting the complete analysis with source codes on my new blog, maybe next week.